# Cloud Firestore - Cannot Get Document Count

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am migrating from Firebase realtime database and previously used the .getChildrenCount method to get the count of items in a specific node.

This method does not appear to have a counterpart in the Cloud Firestore. I am trying to access the answers collection in my database and get the count. Below is my code, everything is reading correctly and I am noting where I begin attempting to get the count of documents in the answers collection:

```
mStoreSelectedPollRef.collection(ANSWERS_LABEL).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    int numberOfPollAnswers = 0;
                    int pollAnswerSize = task.getResult().size();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot answer : task.getResult()){
                        numberOfPollAnswers++;
                    }
                    Log.v("NUMBER OF POLL ANSWERS ", String.valueOf(numberOfPollAnswers));
                    Log.v("SIZE", String.valueOf(pollAnswerSize));
```

//                        addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(numberOfPollAnswers, task.getResult());
                    }
                });

Below is my data structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mStoreSelectedPollRef` seems to be a `DocumentReference`, which points to a single document. The `size()` method only exists on [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot), which you get when you attach a listener to a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have updated code and I am receiving an 'incompatible types' warning

Comment: You're still trying to load a document, where you should be loading a collection. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection. Are you looking for [`mStoreSelectedPollRef .collection("answers")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#collection(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Appreciate the patience, I believe the code above should allow me to access the data I need, though it does not appear to be the solution you recommending as I am still exploring.